# Expected value of wo multiplying random variables

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference, signal-processing

I want to know how to solve an expected value of product of exponential and rayleigh random variable  and in wireless communication.like expression is

$z =|\sqrt{P_n}e^{j\theta_n}|^2$

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: If they are uncorrelated, then $\mathsf{E}(XY)=\mathsf{E}(X)\mathsf{E}(Y)$.

Comment: Note that independence implies uncorrelation.

Comment: no,they are not independence/uncorrelated. @Augustin msm K.Brix

Comment: actually case is that two random variables and both were exponentionally distributed but i have to take square root of one of the two exponentionally random variables and thus one of them becomes rayleigh R.V i have two random variables, 1 exponentionally distributed and other is rayleigh distributed which are multiplying each other and i have to compute their expected value

Comment: And do you know anything about their correlation? If not we can't answer because $E(XY)$ could be anything from $E(X)E(Y)-\sigma_X\sigma_Y$ to $E(X)E(Y)+\sigma_X\sigma_Y$.

Comment: here is equation  z =  \sqrt{P_n}e^{j\theta_n}

Comment: $z =|\sqrt{P_n}e^{j\theta_n}|^2$  Pn and exponential are uncorrelated